# Hud is not displaying after restoring a backup project

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5, unreal-development-kit

so i restored a backup project and i ran into a little problem. my hud is not displaying, the widget blueprints. was wondering if anyone got a clue to why its not showing? Thanks!

i have tried to see if everything was connected properly and it seems like it have. nothing has worked so far but something got messed up when reuploading my backup project

Comment: https://streamable.com/edfnze

here is a video of the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have 3 different versions of Unreal Engine tagged.